# How to handle CORS error with an angular app and a java backend?

Tags: ajax, cors, jersey

I have an angular App that tries to send ajax requests to a java backend (API built with Jersey).

Here is the client request :

```
let settings = {
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/simulator/config",
      "method": "POST",
      "timeout": 0,
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "data": JSON.stringify({
        "fromDate": fromDate,
        "tsIntervalTag": tsIntervalTag,
        "tsIntervalDevice": tsIntervalDevice,
        "devicePerMinute": devicePerMinute,
        "tagPerMinute": tagPerMinute,
        "quantityOfTags": quantityOfTags,
        "quantityOfDevices": quantityOfDevices
      }),
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

And here is the java backend request handler:

```
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response postIt(String body) {
        try {
            //do stuff
            return Response.ok(body, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.serverError().entity(e).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, as **nearly all** answers about CORS state, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is set to `*` wildcard, so from my understanding, the response should get back to the browser.

But the browser console returns the following:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/simulator/config.
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/simulator/config.
>   (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

So what did I miss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like with Jersey, it is better to use filters to set CORS. (At least in my scenario where all requests should be accepted from anywhere (so far)).

So I created the following class (in its own java file):

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("FILTER HERE ");
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // Allow Access from everywhere
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
    }

}
```

And that's is basically it. All requests will go through this and get the correct headers. I do not know why setting the headers in method directly did not work though.

Comment: I had a React app going to be started along with a Java backend app and now it turns out this is a backend server issue. It makes sense when thinking about it. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Also keep an eye on web.xml

I commented this code then it worked, in addition to addint `@CrossOrigin`

**Example**

```
@CrossOrigin
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/otp/")
public class OtpController {
```

```
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>restricted methods</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint/>
    </security-constraint>
```